# Debugging deprecated/renamed PSR-0 classes being requested

Tags: composer, autoloading

After upgrading to 6.2 via WP-CLI I get an error regarding deprecated/renamed PSR-0 classes being requested.

The source comment from WP core says:

> ```
>           /*
>            * Integrators who cannot yet upgrade to the PSR-4 class names can silence deprecations
>            * by defining a `REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS` constant and setting it to `true`.
>            * The constant needs to be defined before the first deprecated class is requested
>            * via this autoloader.
>            */
> ```

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7714010f60a55633bd0ee5c5a0843ef7a4a7f756/wp-includes/Requests/src/Autoload.php#L161

How to upgrade to the PSR-4 class names?

Asked differently, could it be a script autoloaded before WordPress via PSR-0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in [the WP 6.2 Field guide post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/09/wordpress-6-2-field-guide/), and in the post about [the upgrade of the requests library](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/08/requests-library-upgraded-to-2-0-5-in-wordpress-6-2/) that you found the deprecation warning in.

> If your plugin or theme uses Requests directly and supports a wider range of WordPress versions, you may need to conditionally declare the REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS constant as true to silence deprecation notices about the old PSR-0 class names. You should upgrade your code as soon as WordPress 6.2 becomes the minimum WordPress version for your plugin or theme.

If your code uses the `WP_HTTP` APIs then no changes are needed, this only affects code that directly uses the raw Requests API.

For fixing it:

> If your plugin or theme uses Requests directly, and only supports the latest version of WordPress, you should update your code to use the namespaced names. For example, to perform a request with a try-catch using the namespaced names:

```php
// Old: Perform a request with a try-catch in Requests 1.x.
try {
    $response = Requests::request( $url, $headers, $data, $type, $options );
} catch ( Requests_Exception $e ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'http_request_failed', $e->getMessage() );
}
 
// New: Perform a request with a try-catch in Requests 2.x.
try {
    $response = WpOrg\Requests\Requests::request( $url, $headers, $data, $type, $options );
} catch ( WpOrg\Requests\Exception $e ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'http_request_failed', $e->getMessage() );
}
```

The most compatible way to fix this, and prevent it ever happening again, is to use the `WP_HTTP` API and WP functions such as `wp_remote_post` etc